# Regressors with low variance

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, variance

I am a newbie to regression modelling techniques. I have a very basic question.  My dataset has around 60 independent variables and goal is it find the best variables among them. I found that around four regressors have very low variance of say 0.0005,0.007 etc. Is it logical to drop these regressors under the base that they exhibit very low variance and hence cannot predict the dependent variable well. ???
It is actually a ratio between two quantities....  Values ranging between 0.01 to 0.02.....the variance is returned as 0.0005

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Low as compared to what? Try multiplying your regressors by some constant, e.g. $10000$, this will shift the variance. Next, ask yourself if it made your variables anyhow "better" for regression analysis? Did it make your variables convey more information then they carried initially?

There may be two, and only two, reasons why low variance should be a concern:

1. when variance is actually equal to zero, i.e. your regressors are constant. In such case they convey literally no information, so they should be dropped from your analysis.
2. when your variance is *really* small, say $10^{-16}$ (but this may depend on your machine and the software you are using), then you may run into numerical precision issues and it may be worth considering to transforming your data, e.g. by multiplying the regressor by some large constant $c$. In such case you need to remember about the transformation you made since they affect the parameters for those variables (so $\beta/c$ is the parameter value for non-transformed variable).

Comment: It is actually a ratio between two quantities....  Values ranging between 0.01 to 0.02.....the variance is returned as 0.0005

Comment: @Sanju still, what I have said in my answer still applies. There is no such a thing as "objectively low" variance.